# Vue js + Vuetify autocomplete using Yandex Predictor API

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I use Yandex autocomplete words API in my vue js application. Here you can see my [codepen](https://codepen.io/devmansurov/pen/bGdqyOb) example.
Autocomplete work when I enter one work for example `hell` on response get `hello`. But when I enter `hello w` autocomplete return me next possible word as `world`. But how I can remove uncompletely entered last word and push it to autocomplete items and show to user? Also how I can send request when user stop entering for performance?

**Code:**

```
<v-autocomplete
    v-model="select"
    :loading="loading"
    :items="items"
    :search-input.sync="search"
    cache-items
    class="mx-4"
    flat
    hide-no-data
    hide-details
    label="Search..."
    solo-inverted
></v-autocomplete>
```

**Script:**

```
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data() {
    return {
      loading: false,
      items: [],
      search: null,
      select: null,
      states: [

      ]
    };
  },
  watch: {
    search(val) {
      val && val !== this.select && this.querySelections(val);
    }
  },
  methods: {
    querySelections(v) {
      this.loading = true;
      var query = this.search.split(" ").join("+")
      console.log("Search query")
      console.log(query)
      var url ="https://predictor.yandex.net/api/v1/predict.json/complete?key=key&q="+query+"&lang=en"
      axios.get(url).then(res => {
        console.log("Next or current possible word")
        console.log(res.data.text[0])
        this.states = res.data.text
        this.items = this.states.filter(e => {
          return (e || "").toLowerCase()
            .indexOf((v || "")
            .toLowerCase()) > -1;
        });
        this.loading = false
      })
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You really need 2 separate things:

1. The `filter` proper where you can do what you want, in this case you remove split the word and take the section you want. 
   Something like:

```
:filter="customFilter"
...
customFilter(item, queryText, itemText) {
     queryText = queryText.split(' ')[1]
    }
```

2. A debounce function for performance, I would recommend [Lodash debounce](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#debounce) for that

Comment: Can you show me example filtering for my case in codepen? @Michael

Comment: It's not work for me. I tried your custom filter but not it solve my problem